# Spiral array from a random starting position

Tags: c++, arrays, random

Consider an array

```
0000
0000
0000
```

Then a number generated in a complete random position in the array

```
0000
0000
00x0
```

What I want to do is knowing the position of the number, make it go through the array in a spiral order. I can't find something in c++, it's the only language I know.

I already know how to go in spiral order from element [0][0] to [1][2] (clockwise), but how do I do it if my initial position is random? Then, how do I go backwards, anti-clockwise? And so on, but the start should be from that random position(2 numbers generated random will be the positions).

Comment: What do you mean by `spiral order`? If it means hopping from array[0][3] to array[1][0] and from array[1][3] to array[2][0] and so on I would suggest that you simply use an one-dimensional array, interpret it as two-dimensional and iterate over it just by incrementing and decrementing an index.

Comment: Also, in your specific example, if I go clockwise (from (2,2) -> (2,1) -> .... -> (1,3) -> (2,3)) How do I continue a "spiral" when I'm stuck in the lower right corner? In other words, I think that a "spiral order" may not always be possible depending on start position and direction, unless you have a precise definition that accounts for such cases...

Comment: I mean [0][0] [0][1] [0][2] [0][3] [1][3] [2][3] [2][2] [2][1] [2][0] [1][0] etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code only works if you point is in the center of your array. If you add correct bounds checking this should work as you describe. I made the assumption(based on your first example) that when you finish all existing elements you move to the outer set. ie

```
0000
0000
00x0
```

becomes

```
2222
2111
21x1
```

touching them in this order

```
  6 7 8 9
 11 1 2 3
 10 5 X 4
```

with 2 represent the second circle and 1 the first circle.

the output from this program  is (i just stored the"radius" in each element)

```
pre traversal
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 

post traversal
2 2 2 2 2 
2 1 1 1 2 
2 1 0 1 2 
2 1 1 1 2 
2 2 2 2 2 



// what is the maximum possible radius
int getMaxRadius(int x, int y, int size)
{
int toReturn = std::abs(size-x);
if(std::abs(size-y) > toReturn)
    toReturn = std::abs(size -y);

return toReturn ;
}

//is the curernt element next to the current center
bool nextTo(int xCenter, int yCenter, int x, int y, int radius )
{
//if it
if(std::abs(xCenter - x) > radius || std::abs(yCenter - y) > radius)
{
    return false;
}
return true;
}


void circular(int** array, int xCenter, int yCenter, int size)
{
int curRadius = 1;
int maxRadius = getMaxRadius(xCenter, yCenter,size);

while( curRadius<maxRadius) 
{

    //start to the top left of the cur radius
    int curX = xCenter - curRadius; 
    int curY = yCenter - curRadius;

    //go right
    while(nextTo(xCenter, yCenter, curX, curY, curRadius ))
    {
        array[curX][curY] = curRadius;
        curX ++;
    }
    curX--;//we went one too far

    //go down
    while(nextTo(xCenter, yCenter, curX, curY, curRadius ))
    {
        array[curX][curY] = curRadius;
        curY ++;
    }
    curY--;//we went one too far


    //go left   
    while(nextTo(xCenter, yCenter, curX, curY, curRadius ))
    {
        array[curX][curY] = curRadius;
        curX --;
    }
    curX++;//we went one too far

    //goUP
    while(nextTo(xCenter, yCenter, curX, curY, curRadius ))
    {
        array[curX][curY] = curRadius;
        curY --;
    }
    curY++;//we went one too far
    curRadius ++;
}
}
```